# AWS CodeCommit SSH connection stopped working suddenly (It was worked well before)

Tags: ssh, aws-cdk, aws-codecommit

I'm working for an AWS CDK Pipeline with a source repository in AWS CodeCommit.

I set the pipeline works with the specific branch push in the repository. 
And I used SSH connection 
(IAM USER > security credentials > SSH keys for AWS CodeCommit) 
to pull/push the source code from/to the repository.

It worked well in 2~3 months..

But today it stopped suddenly.

I searched some references but confused.. 
As I know, I can't set allowed host on CodeCommit by myself...

The below is a capture which I tried to find a clue...
I don't know well about SSH. Could you give me some hint if you get the reason on here?
[image]

I replaced the SSH pub key on the IAM users > security credentials but no lucks.

And if someone know why this happen suddenly, please let me know.

(Can it be the cause that too much push in short time?)

FYI, I waited 30 minutes and tried again, but no luck...

- Q1. Could you give me some hint what should I do with that capture?
- Q2. Why this happen suddenly..?

Answer (score 0):

It is working again after 1 day